# Uninstalled MacVim, now can't use regular Vim?

Tags: vim, terminal, alias

I got a new machine at work. The previous developer had macvim installed. When typing 'vim' in the terminal, the macvim program would open. I uninstalled macvim because I don't use it. Now when I type 'vim' in the terminal, it says, "Sorry, cannot find MacVim.app." I want to just run vim in the terminal. Is this an alias or something? How can I quickly fix!

Comment: put into the Terminal `which vim` return. What does it say?

Comment: Is there something in your ~/.bashrc ? When i type vim in Iterm it opens vim not Macvim - Also installed on my mac

Comment: Or it is in the ~/.profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can enter this into the terminal:

```
which vim
alias
```

to see info about defined aliases and what happens when you try to run vim

Answer (score 1):

The previous user installed the `mvim` script that comes with MacVim somewhere in the `$PATH` or elsewhere and probably symlinked it or created an alias.

To get rid of that behaviour, try the following:

- look into your `~/.bashrc` or whatever if there's an alias that point at `mvim`
- look everywhere in your `$PATH` for a `mvim` script, maybe

  ```
  $ which mvim
  ```

  will do
- make sure `/usr/bin/vim` is a real Vim executable and not a symlink with this command

  ```
  $ file /usr/bin/vim
  ```

If it's symlinked then you have trouble, If it's only an alias simply remove it. If you don't want to mess around too much, you can add an alias to `/usr/bin/vim` in your `~/.profile` or whatever.

Whatever you do, I'd recommend you to re-install MacVim as it is a lot better than the default Vim in almost every way.

Answer (score 0):

Is there still a file here: /usr/bin/vim ?

If that got deleted, then you'll need to reinstall vim.

I suggest using [Link](https://brew.sh/) as your package manager